# I can't remove a path from the plot

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am making a compound plot. Among the features to be implemented there is the possibility of making the plots appear and disappear dynamically.

With circle and line I've not problem with the code below:

```
svg.selectAll('circle').remove();
svg.selectAll('line').remove();
```

But I cannot delete the paths from the displayed items.

I have proceeded to severals attempts that are present in the lambda of the useEffect hooks, but they doesn't works.

```js
const useState = React.useState;
const useRef = React.useRef;
const useEffect = React.useEffect;
const Fragment = React.Fragment;

const select = d3.select;
const scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear;
const axisBottom = d3.axisBottom;
const axisLeft = d3.axisLeft;
const line = d3.line;
const curveCardinal = d3.curveCardinal;

const PathPlot = () => {

  const [xAxisData] = useState({
    min: 100,
    max: 700
  });

  const [yAxisData] = useState({
    min: 200,
    max: 500
  });

  const [meta] = useState({
    xWidth: 600,
    yWidth: 300,
  });

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleRemove = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }

  const [plot] = useState({
    color: 'red',
    width: '5px',
    line: [{
      x: '120',
      y: '210'
    }, {
      x: '220',
      y: '230'
    }, {
      x: '320',
      y: '250'
    }, {
      x: '380',
      y: '270'
    }, {
      x: '450',
      y: '290'
    }]

  });

  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {

    if (svgRef.current) {

      const svg = select(svgRef.current);

      // X-AXIS
      const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([xAxisData.min, xAxisData.max])
        .range([0, meta.xWidth]);

      const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale);

      svg
        .select(".x-axis")
        .style("transform", `translateY(${meta.yWidth}px)`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y-AXIS
      const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([yAxisData.min, yAxisData.max])
        .range([meta.yWidth, 0]);

      const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);

      svg
        .select(".y-axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      // line plot
      if (visible) {
        const myLine = line()
          .x(value => xScale(value.x))
          .y(value => yScale(value.y))
          .curve(curveCardinal);

        svg
          .select(".line-plot")
          .data([plot.line])
          .join("path")
          .attr("d", value => myLine(value))
          .attr("fill", "transparent")
          .attr("stroke", () => plot.color)
          .attr("stroke-width", () => plot.width);
      }


    }
    return () => {
      if (svgRef.current !== undefined) {
        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        svg
          .selectAll('.line-plot')
          .attr('d', '')
          .attr("fill", 'trasparent')
          .attr("stroke", 'transparent')
          .attr("stroke-width", '0px')
          .attr("opacity", '0');
      }
    }
  }, [xAxisData, yAxisData, meta, line]);

  return ( <
    Fragment >
    <
    svg viewBox = {
      `0 0 ${meta.xWidth} ${meta.yWidth}`
    }
    ref = {
      svgRef
    } >
    <
    g className = "x-axis" / >
    <
    g className = "y-axis" / >
    <
    path className = "line-plot" / >
    <
    /svg> <
    div onClick = {
      handleRemove
    } > REMOVE < /div> <
    /Fragment>

  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < PathPlot / > , document.querySelector("body"));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want to *remove* the path or just hide it so you can make it appear again later? Do you want to remove the path while keeping any other lines in the line chart visible? Do you want to change the underlying data so the path never re-appears or do you want the path to show up again on subsequent draws?

Comment: I want to be able to hide the path elements.depending on a Boolean value of any type, the single path must be able to change the visibility. For me, the best case is to delete the attributes entered during insertion. In a chart with a single path I need to be able to make it visible or invisible. In the chart with two or more paths I need to be able to make the single path visible or invisible.

Comment: The big picture is: the elements in the chart should be visible or invisible based on a boolean value  and in addition they should be able to display different datasets passed as props to the component. For other elements of the chart I eliminate them in the lambda of useEffect hooks, but for the path element I cannot intervene in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example would be the following. I add `visible` to the list of dependencies for `useEffect` and always draw the line. I just give it opacity 0 if visible is false, and 1 otherwise.

```js
const useState = React.useState;
const useRef = React.useRef;
const useEffect = React.useEffect;
const Fragment = React.Fragment;

const select = d3.select;
const scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear;
const axisBottom = d3.axisBottom;
const axisLeft = d3.axisLeft;
const line = d3.line;
const curveCardinal = d3.curveCardinal;

const PathPlot = () => {

  const [xAxisData] = useState({
    min: 100,
    max: 700
  });

  const [yAxisData] = useState({
    min: 200,
    max: 500
  });

  const [meta] = useState({
    xWidth: 600,
    yWidth: 300,
  });

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleRemove = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }

  const [plot] = useState({
    color: 'red',
    width: '5px',
    line: [{
      x: '120',
      y: '210'
    }, {
      x: '220',
      y: '230'
    }, {
      x: '320',
      y: '250'
    }, {
      x: '380',
      y: '270'
    }, {
      x: '450',
      y: '290'
    }]

  });

  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("hi");
    if (svgRef.current) {

      const svg = select(svgRef.current);

      // X-AXIS
      const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([xAxisData.min, xAxisData.max])
        .range([0, meta.xWidth]);

      const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale);

      svg
        .select(".x-axis")
        .style("transform", `translateY(${meta.yWidth}px)`)
        .call(xAxis);

      // Y-AXIS
      const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([yAxisData.min, yAxisData.max])
        .range([meta.yWidth, 0]);

      const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);

      svg
        .select(".y-axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      // line plot
      if (visible) {
        const myLine = line()
          .x(value => xScale(value.x))
          .y(value => yScale(value.y))
          .curve(curveCardinal);

        svg
          .select(".line-plot")
          .data([plot.line])
          .join("path")
          .attr("d", value => myLine(value))
          .attr("fill", "transparent")
          .attr("stroke", () => plot.color)
          .attr("stroke-width", () => plot.width);
      }


    }
    return () => {
      if (svgRef.current !== undefined) {
        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        svg
          .selectAll('.line-plot')
          .attr('d', '')
          .attr("fill", 'trasparent')
          .attr("stroke", 'transparent')
          .attr("stroke-width", '0px')
          .attr("opacity", '0');
      }
    }
  }, [xAxisData, yAxisData, meta, line, visible]);

  return ( <
    Fragment >
    <
    svg viewBox = {
      `0 0 ${meta.xWidth} ${meta.yWidth}`
    }
    ref = {
      svgRef
    } >
    <
    g className = "x-axis" / >
    <
    g className = "y-axis" / >
    <
    path className = "line-plot" / >
    <
    /svg> <
    div onClick = {
      handleRemove
    } > REMOVE < /div> <
    /Fragment>

  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < PathPlot / > , document.querySelector("body"));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: trivial mistake for a simple workaround. If I don't receive solutions more in line with d3.js than with react I will check your answer.